# Hadoop for JSON files

Tags: json, hadoop

Would you have any hints on what would be the best way to deal with files containing JSON entries and Hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724868/hadoop-java-mapreduce-parsing-json-with-jackson-issues)

You can also use [JAQL](http://code.google.com/p/jaql/). Its the easiest way to deal with JSON in Map Reduce. Bad thing is that you will have to learn JAQL (unless you know it already) !!

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice article on this from the Hadoop in Practice book:

- http://java.dzone.com/articles/hadoop-practice

Answer (score 3):

Twitter's [elephant-bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird) library has a JsonStringToMap class which you can use with Pig.

Comment: Keep in mind. This goes only one level deep (source: comment in JsonStringToMap.java)

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB** is a good option when you are dealing with JSON. MongoDB and Hadoop are a powerful combination and can be used together to deliver complex analytics and data processing for data stored in MongoDB.   *http://www.mongodb.org/*