# Multistorage with avro?

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I have a single file containing multiple avro records. Each record contains a unique "name". How do I load and store files such that each file represents a record that corresponds with a given name?

Here is my avro schema:

```
{
    "type": "records",
    "name": "XXItem",
    "namespace": "com.xxx.xxx",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "data",
            "type":  {"type": "map", "values" : ["string", "long", "int"]}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick check seems to indicate that avro, is simply using JSON for data storage.
By looking for solutions for handling JSON in general, you should be able to come up with something that works for you.

This could be a starting point: [Hadoop for JSON files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942483/hadoop-for-json-files)